# Rounding down value

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, round-function

I made a layer in which I have a column with a function, that calculates volume. For Example:

```
a * b * c * indicator

2.5 * 1.2 * 2.3 * 0.62
```

In this example, the answer is 4,278 but I need to round it down to 4,27 - I can't round it up like function "Round" does - 4,28). Does anyone know how to round it down? I found a solution for ArcGIS but not for QGIS. As far as I understand, function "floor" will round it down to whole number.

My actual function is:

```
if(
"b" = 0, 
round(((( "c" - "indicator" ) * ("c" - "indicator" )*3.14)/40000)* "a" ,2) , 
round("a" * "b" * "c" * "indicator",2))
```

I hold all layers in the local PostgreSQL database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are looking for the `floor` function

`floor(x * 100) / 100` will give you `x` rounded down to 2 decimal places.
ex: `floor(4.278 * 100) / 100` -> 4.27

```
if(
"b" = 0, 
floor(((( "c" - "indicator" ) * ("c" - "indicator" )*3.14)/40000)* "a" * 100) / 100 , 
floor("a" * "b" * "c" * "indicator" * 100) / 100)
```

ps: you have to multiply by 100 because the `floor` function in QGIS doesn't take a second parameter like `round`. So it is needed to multiply by 100 -> floor -> divide by 100 to have the result round down to 2 decimal places.

Comment: It works! Oh boy, thank you so much!

"you have to multiply by 100 because the floor function in QGIS doesn't take a second parameter like round" - I didn't know about that - now It is so simple!

Comment: No problem it is just a simple but non-obvious thing that once you know, you don't really think about it anymore and remember.